# Comparing array values in nested foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I've two arrays:

```
$rooms = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$reserved_rooms = [4, 7];
```

I would like to print this array like this:

```
1
2
3
Room 4 is reserved
5
6
Room 7 is reserved
```

Her is my code:

```
$rooms = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$reserved_rooms = [4, 7]; 

foreach($rooms as $key=>$val){
    foreach($reserved_rooms as $val2){
        if($val == $val2){
            echo $val2." room is reserved";
        }   
        else
            echo $val."<br>";
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4 room is reserved4
5
5
6
6
7
7 room is reserved8
8
9
9
```

Comment: In reaction to the comments on the answers. Specify a dummy but correct example. This will make it easier to help you find the best solution. Iterating over arrays is time consuming and probably not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move your `echo` outside the loop.

```
$rooms = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$reserved_rooms = [4, 7]; 

foreach($rooms as $key=>$val){
    $isReserved = false; // add this

    foreach($reserved_rooms as $val2){
        if($val == $val2){
            $isReserved = true;
            break; // is reserved, no need to check the other values
        }
    }

    if ($isReserved) { // now decide whether it is reserved or not
        echo $val." room is reserved";
    } else {
        echo $val."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) to check if a value exists in the array.

```
foreach($rooms as $room) {
   if( in_array($room, $reserved_rooms) ) {
      echo $room .' is reserved.' . PHP_EOL;
      continue;
   }
   echo $room . PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://eval.in/508706

Comment: yeah, you are right. but is it possible to do not using in_array() function?

Comment: ...why do you not want to use a native function?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ wouldn't `continue` also echo the second echo ? Sorry if I'm mistaken

Comment: No, [`continue`](http://php.net/continue) will finish that iteration and move on to the next

Comment: My problem is I can't use in_array(), coz it's other type comparison, not exact value. I just give this example to explain more simple

Comment: Then use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) every value. Unsure what you mean by saying "not exact value".

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not want to use `in_array()` function :

```
$rooms = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$reserved_rooms = [4, 7]; 

array_map(function ($room) use ($reserved_rooms) { 
    foreach($reserved_rooms as $reserved_room) {
       if ($reserved_room == $room) { 
           print "Room $room is reserved\n";
           return;
       }
    }
    print "$room\n"; 
}, $rooms);
```

https://eval.in/508743

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
foreach($rooms as $key=>$val){
    if(in_array($val, $reserved_rooms){
        echo $val." room is reserved";
    }else{
        echo $val
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rooms = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$reserved_rooms = [4, 7]; 

foreach($rooms as $key=>$val){
    $flag = false;
    foreach($reserved_rooms as $val2){
        if($val == $val2){
            echo "Room ".$val2." is reserved<br />";
            $flag=true;
            break;
        }        
    }
    if($flag == false){
        echo $val."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the part where it looks identical to http://stackoverflow.com/a/35035422/3000179. Plus, code-only answers are discouraged

Comment: Please have a look at the code that you think identical. The accepted answer give output like `1
2
3
4 room is reserved5
6
7 room is reserved8
9`
And my code give output like `1
2
3
Room 4 is reserved
5
6
Room 7 is reserved
8
9
`
That exactly what you want to print as described your question.